# How to update UI elements of an activity via Espresso test methods?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to write a test case for my activity. I have a method in my activity that updates my UI.

```
public void setBooking(Booking booking)
{
    if (booking == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.mBooking = booking;
    this.mBookingExt.updateUI();
}
```

and this is my test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LocatingActivityTest
{
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<BookingActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(BookingActivity.class);

    private BookingActivity mBookingActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        mBookingActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
        mBookingActivity.setBooking(BookingTest.getStandardTaxi()); // << My Fake Booking Object

        onView(withId(R.id.book_now)).perform(click());
    }

    @Test
    public void viewsMustBeVisible()
    {
        onView(withId(R.id.locating_text)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.sonarView)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.cancel_booking)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error when I run the test:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I think `@Before` is running on UI thread so have no idea this complain comes from where! [This is my reference](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/test/rule/UiThreadTestRule.html) (`ActivityTestRule` extends `UiThreadTestRule`).

So I decided to change the architecture of class a bit. So `setup()` and `viewsMustBeVisible()` changed to this:

```
    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        mBookingTaxiActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @UiThreadTest // from android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest
    public void viewsMustBeVisible()
    {
        mBookingTaxiActivity.setBooking(BookingTest.getStandardTaxi()); // << My Fake Booking Object

        onView(withId(R.id.fab_booking)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.locating_text)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.sonarView)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.locating_cancel_booking)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
    }
```

However, I'm getting following error this time:

> java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Finally I changed above method to run the test on UI thread:

```
    @Test
    public void viewsMustBeVisible()
    {
        mBookingTaxiActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mBookingTaxiActivity.setBooking(BookingTest.getStandardTaxi()); // << My Fake Booking Object

                onView(withId(R.id.fab_booking)).perform(click());
                onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
                onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).perform(click());

                onView(withId(R.id.locating_text)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
                onView(withId(R.id.sonarView)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
                onView(withId(R.id.locating_cancel_booking)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        });
    }
```

The problem here is test never gets done. I'm waiting 6-7 minutes and its progress indicator is still spinning and seems never gets done.

I guess I have examined all ways to update my Booking object as well as UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, I got it don after a lot of hours. I'm not sure what is the difference but I moved UI thread works in Activity. New Test method Look likes this:

```
    @Test
    public void viewsMustBeVisible()
    {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab_booking)).perform(click());

        mBookingTaxiActivity.setTestBooking(BookingTest.getStandardTaxi());

        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.locating_text)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.sonarView)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.locating_cancel_booking)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
    }
```

and I created a method in activity side to update my object:

```
    // Required just for Testing purposes
    @VisibleForTesting
    public void setTestBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        if (booking == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.mBooking = booking;

        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                BookingActivity.this.mBookingExt.updateUI();
                findViewById(R.id.booking_book_now).setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps you if you have same problem.